# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{

Tags: python, excel, api, url, sharepoint

I am authenticating SharePoint using python . I am able to authenticate successfully but I am not able to read the excel files that is in the document folder .
This is the  code below. I tried to see what is causing this error in forums  but I was not able to find a solid solution .

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import glob
import path
import tempfile
from pandas import DataFrame


#Then proceed to authenticate to your SharePoint account

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials

url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepointauthentication/'

app_principal = {
'client_id': 'b7d5d223-2442-4205-a099-f486f7bd24b8',
'client_secret': '****************************',
}

relative_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Sharepointauthentication/Shared%20Documents/example.xlsx?d=w24291c7f742242198e3a7a70e21cc40f&csf=1&web=1&e=yAV89z"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_principal['client_id'], client_secret=app_principal['client_secret']):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print('Authenticated into sharepoint app for: ',web.properties['Title'])

response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)

#save data to BytesIO stream


bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_table(bytes_file_obj)
print(df)
```

This is the error I am generating
Authenticated into sharepoint app for:  Sharepoint authentication
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression "web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('https:/company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Sharepointauthentication/Shared Documents/example.xlsx" is not valid."}}}]
Index: []

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7km.png)

The relative_url is from file -> copy link and not the browser url

Any help  or code change suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `relative_url` is clearly invalid and not even relative. A URL *can't* have a colon except for when specifying a port. 5 lines before that you're creating `url` correctly

Comment: Try using `relative_url ="Shared%20Documents/example.xlsx?d=w24291c7f742242198e3a7a70e21cc40f&csf=1&web=1&e=yAV89z"`

Comment: That Url did not work , it generates the same error as before